# Big-O Runtime for Program Made

Tags: java, list, time, heap, big-o

I am trying to create code that runs at a particular time. My first method should run at worst in O(log k). This is my method:

```
public void count(T x) {
    if(heap.size() < k){
        heap.add(x);
    }
    else if(heap.size() == k && x.compareTo((T) heap.peek()) > 0){
        heap.remove(); 
        heap.add(x);
    }
}
```

I am having trouble calculating the run time. The heap.size() call I am pretty sure is constant time. While the add() method runs in O(log k) time. This is true of the remove() method as well. The other comparison should also only take a constant time. Hence I am pretty sure my program runs in O(log k). Can someone confirm?

My other method is supposed to run in O(k log k) time. This is my method:

```
public List<T> kbest() {
    //empty queue first and then restore
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    int size = heap.size(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        list.add(0, heap.poll());
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
        heap.add(list.get(j));
    }
    return list;
}
```

This one is more confusing for me to understand. add() in a list runs in constant time. While add() in a heap runs in O(log k). Getting the size of the heap is constant and so is the size of the list (which is done "j" times). Does this make my runtime O(n) as in linear?

Comment: `kbest()` is `O(k log k)` (or `O(n log n)`). The first `for` loop is `O(k)` while the second one is `O(k log k)` because of `heap.add()`. Correction: `list.add(int, element)` is actually insert, which is an `O(n)` operation due to shifting. Therefore this method is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: If you loop through an entire list, as you do, that makes it `O(n)` such that the logarithms really don't matter.  The execution time of the entire algorithm is "on the order of" the size of the list.  If the list is twice as big, it will take twice as long.  "The time required to process one of those entries" is not the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this line by line.

```
public void count(T x) {
    if(heap.size() < k){ // O(1)
        heap.add(x); // O(log k)
    }
    else if(heap.size() == k && // O(1)
                x.compareTo(
                    (T) heap.peek()) > 0) { // O(1)
        heap.remove(); // O(log k)
        heap.add(x); // O(log k)
    }
}
```

1. If it goes into `if` block: `O(1 * log k)`, which is `O(log k)`.
2. If it goes into `else if` block: `O(max(1, 1) * max(log k, log k))`, which is `O(log k)`.
3. So you are correct - this method is `O(log k)`.

Now the second method:

```
public List<T> kbest() {
    //empty queue first and then restore
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    int size = heap.size();  // O(1)
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // O(n)
        list.add(0, heap.poll()); // O(n)
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){ // O(n)
        heap.add(list.get(j)); // O(log n)
    }
    return list;
}
```

1. `heap.size` is `O(1)`.
2. First `for` loop is `O(n * n)`, which is `O(n^2)`.
3. Second `for` loop is `O(n * log n)`, which is `O(n log n)`.
4. Final complexity is `O(max(1, n^2, n log n))`, which is `O(n^2)`.

#### Update

To improve the time complexity of `kbest()`, you can use the `add()` method which is `O(1)`.

Of course, the order would be reversed. You can easily use `Collections.reverse(list)`, which would be `O(n)`. Since this would be performed outside the loop, the time complexity would not be multiplied.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. This makes a lot of sense. One last question. If I were to try to make the latter method O(nlogn), is there another add method similar that could help me reduce the run time?

Comment: @A.Torres Updated.